# azure search sample Hotel data search for exact match multiple items

Tags: azure, search

When I try to query the hotel data sample of Azure search https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-dotnet-samples through api its working fine

Below finds hotel with name as Twin or Cliff exact match

```
{
    "search": "\"Twin\",\"Cliff\"",
    "count": true,
    "searchFields":"HotelName",
    "highlight": "HotelName"
}
```

However when I try the same using sdk code its not working

```
 List<string> searchTextList = new List<string> { "Twin", "Cliff" };
 var formattedSearchText = searchTextList.Select(x => string.Format("\\\"{0}\\\"",  x)).ToList();
 string combinedSearchText = string.Join(",", formattedSearchText);
    
 string searchText = "\"" + combinedSearchText + "\"";
 Console.WriteLine(searchText);

 response = srchclient.Search<Hotel>(searchText, options);
```

Console output of the search text

```
"\"Twin\",\"Cliff\""
```

Tried to code it directly ""Twin","Cliff"" when triggering search and that was working but if I substitute with generated searchstring its not working

```
     response = srchclient.Search<Hotel>("\"Twin\",\"Cliff\"", options);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are constructing the search query string incorrectly when using the SDK code.

[image]

The below code is search using Azure Cognitive Search with c# using [Azure.Search.Documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-dotnet-sdk)

```cs
   string searchServiceEndPoint = "<Your search service endpoint>";
   string queryApiKey =  "<Your admin API key>";
   string indexName = "hotels"; // Index name

   SearchClientOptions options = new SearchClientOptions();
   SearchClient srchclient = new SearchClient(new Uri(searchServiceEndPoint), indexName, new AzureKeyCredential(queryApiKey), options);

   List<string> searchTextList = new List<string> { "Twin", "Cliff" };
   var formattedSearchText = searchTextList.Select(x => $"\"{x}\"").ToList();
   string combinedSearchText = string.Join(",", formattedSearchText);

   SearchOptions searchOptions = new SearchOptions()
   {
       SearchFields = { "HotelName" },
       HighlightFields = { "HotelName" },
       IncludeTotalCount = true
   };

   Console.WriteLine($"Search Text: {combinedSearchText}");

   SearchResults<Hotel> response = srchclient.Search<Hotel>(combinedSearchText, searchOptions);

   foreach (SearchResult<Hotel> result in response.GetResults())
   {
       Console.WriteLine($"Hotel Name: {result.Document.HotelName}");
   }


public class Hotel
{
    public string HotelName { get; set; }
    // Other hotel properties
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: This will do partial match. I need exact match similar to filter behavior, that is why I had to surround it with \".

Comment: by using the searchMode parameter in your search options. You would set it to "all" to ensure that all terms in the search query must be found exactly in the documents.  exact match similar to a filter behavior ` SearchMode = SearchMode.All`

Comment: If I use all it will try to find all the search terms in a single document that is not the intention eg => {
    "search": "\"continental breakfast\" \"free wifi\"",
    "count": true,
    "searchFields":"Tags",
    "highlight": "Tags"
}  Here i need to find exact tag match to either free wifi or continental breakfast not both tags in the same hotel document

Comment: achieve this by constructing a search query with multiple expressions using the logical OR operator (|). string combinedSearchText = string.Join(" | ", formattedSearchText);

Comment: Hi we don't need to escape it cause the SDK escapes it when it serializes so instead of   var formattedSearchText = searchTextList.Select(x => $"\"{x}\"").ToList(); we can just give only adding double quotes   var formattedSearchText = searchTextList.Select(x => "\"" + x + "\"").ToList(); for actual match

Comment: yes, well also use the formattedSearchText like this also ```var formattedSearchText = searchTextList.Select(x => "\"" + x + "\"").ToList();```